# Getting clipped Landsat RGB image to render correctly in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, clip, landsat

I downloaded Landsat 8 tiff bands 1-7 into Arcmap 10.7 and then used the Composite Band tool to create a RGB raster composite image. In order to have the Landsat image render correctly I had to reassign the bands so that Red was band 4, Green was 3, and Blue was 2.

[image]

I then used the Clip tool to clip the raster using a polygon layer, but the resulting RGB raster is rendering incorrectly even though the bands are assigned the same way. The clipped raster appears off-color and tinted in regions, and is not the same image quality as the first raster so I think it has to do with the RBG band assignment.

But I've tried different band assignment combos thinking that the bands were shuffled during the extraction and band 3 isn't really 3, etc., but no luck. Is there a solution to render the clipped raster like the original, or would it work if I re-assign bands AFTER I clip to raster for it to render properly?

[image]

Comment: It's not rendering incorrectly, just differently because you've changed the image statistics.  The original band is not the "correct" way to render anyway, it's just the default stretch applied by ArcMap, there's no one true way to render, you can easily change it. I think it looks too dark anyway.  Regardless, you can set the clipped raster to use the same stretch and statistics as the original if you want.

Comment: Okay thanks, I agree that the first image is too dark and I can work with the different stretch settings to improve the image quality for each raster. That its possible to adjust the histogram line for each band is neat, but requires skill. Yet the raster is dramatically improved by just selecting standard deviation instead of percent clipped. Much appreciated!